# How to filter words that contain atleast 2 vowels from a series?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I am unable to understand the mask variable in the code below. The code is basically to filter out the words in the given series in which there are more than 2 variables.

```
# Input
ser = pd.Series(['Apple', 'Orange', 'Plan', 'Python', 'Money'])

# Solution
from collections import Counter
mask = ser.map(lambda x: sum([Counter(x.lower()).get(i, 0) for i in list('aeiou')]) >= 2)
ser[mask]
```

Can someone please help me in understanding this in a better way?

Comment: the answers provided below are the equivalent of the solution, but IMHO, simpler to understand

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`Series.str.count`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.count.html) with regex for test all values in `[]` with ignore lowercase/uppercase:

```
print (ser[ser.str.count('(?i)[aeiou]') >=2])
0     Apple
1    Orange
4     Money
dtype: object
```

Another solution:

```
import re
print (ser[ser.str.count('[aeiou]', re.I) >=2])
0     Apple
1    Orange
4     Money
dtype: object
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
import re
mask = ser.str.count('a|e|i|o|u', re.IGNORECASE) >= 2
ser[mask]
```

Output:

```
0     Apple
1    Orange
4     Money
dtype: object
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import pandas as pd
series=pd.Series(['red','Green','orange','pink','yellow','white'])
for i in series:
    a=0
    for j in i:
        if j in ['a','e','i','o','u','A','E','I','O','U']:
            a=a+1
            if a>=2:
                print(i)
                break
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Could you please format your answer appropriately? :)